# DAX to show rows with null date values in selected date slicer range

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a typical scenario as below.
I have a student table and it contains four columns as below :-

**1.StudentID
2.StudentName
3.LastAttendanceDate
4.StudentType**

Now there are some null values in the date column LastAttendanceDate.Is it possible to use a date slicer to show these values of the students who have LastAttendanceDate column value as null? In simple words: Say you are a student who went to a school on Monday, Tuesday and Friday and you were absent on Wednesday and Thursday so here Wednesday and Thursday are the days where you were absent in the week and we need to display these records in the table visualization.

**My excel Input data:-**

```
StudentID   StudentName LastAttendanceDate  StudentType

    100             Mary    02-05-2011 10:45    Fulltime
    100             Mary                        Fulltime
    100             Mary    04-05-2011 12:45    Fulltime
    100             Mary    06-05-2011 15:45    Fulltime
    100             Mary                        Fulltime
    100             Mary    08-05-2011 19:45    Fulltime
    100             Mary    09-05-2011 12:45    Fulltime
    101             John    02-05-2011 10:45    Part Time
    101             John    03-05-2011 11:23    Part Time
    101             John    04-05-2011 10:45    Part Time
    101             John    06-05-2011 15:49    Part Time
    101             John                        Part Time
    101             John    08-05-2011 19:45    Part Time
    101             John    09-05-2011 12:45    Part Time
```

so here I need to dynamically find in the week/month range or any dynamic date range say from date range 02-05-2011 and 08-05-2011 or 02-05-2011 and 09-05-2011 or even 06-05-2011 and 09-05-2011,  the students who were absent and show it in my table visualization.

Can anyone provide an approach or any helpful DAX? Appreciate all the help

My present visualization looks like this :

[image: My present visualization]

I want to show the students who were absent in the given time range as selected in the date slicer.

so if I slide the date slicer as per minimum and maximum ranges, it should show all the rows of students who were absent or with null values for Last Attendance Date column in those time range.

Kind regards

Sameer

Comment: With your data as it is, this isn't feasible because there is no inherent row ordering with DAX. Thus the null rows aren't "between" anything.

Comment: If possible, you could expand your table with 1 column. This column could represent the "NeededAttendanceDate". With something like that, you can filter for an inbetween date.